# What is the use of default.html in MS bot?

Tags: bots, botframework

In MS bot, there's an html file default.html.

Currently I see it is being launched each time my bot is deployed\executed. 
Is there any other use for it? Maybe when registering it?

Comment: Can you explain what the link is with Robot Framework: the Test Automation tooling?

Comment: Sorry edited the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that page is just an landing page and can be seen from outside by anyone who knows the [Messaging Endpoint](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#registering) of your bot. And this is not an "help page" (as is mentioned in comments). This is not a thing to worry about. You can simply edit and make a simple landing page, and suggest users to go out of that page (if they accidentally entered there), or redirect them to your bot page.

Answer (score 2):

The `Default.html` in your Bot Framework is just for an "introduction" page whenever you open your Bot in your browser. You can modify it whatever you want and it won't affect the behavior of your Bot.

Comment: What do you mean? my users just have a link to my chat bot and they don't see that page. I see it only when I deploy my bot. Who else would see it?

Comment: Yes, typically, it's not for your end-users to see. It's just an "help page" similar to the default landing page that you will see when you create an ASP.NET Web API project.